# scrapy crawl command uses wrong python interpreter (not current)

Tags: python, scrapy, virtualenv

I'm trying to run `scrapy` spider like; `scrapy crawl myspider` but it raises an error.

I noticed that this error is because `scrapy` is being run with `python 3.5` instead of `python 3.6`.

```
(sport_databasevenv) futilestudio@DRUHY-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01-1538126914964-s-2vcpu-2gb-fra1-:~/sport_database/scraping$ scrapy crawl op_index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 249, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
```

But when I do this I see that the activated env uses python 3.6:

```
(sport_databasevenv) futilestudio@DRUHY-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01-1538126914964-s-2vcpu-2gb-fra1-:~/sport_database/scraping$ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, May  3 2018, 10:08:28) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

So where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have `scrapy` installed in your virtualenv? You could check with `pip install scrapy` while your virtualenv is enabled

Comment: Yes, it is installed, I've checked it.

Comment: You can check `which scrapy` to see from where it's being executed. If its not the one from your venv you can run it manually like: `python venv/bin/scrapy ...`